# Codeception can't find class when running single test

Tags: php, composer-php, codeception

I'm writing the API test suite for a project I'm currently working on.

I can successfully run the suite using

```
codecept run api
```

and all the tests are passing successfully, but whenever I try running a single test using

```
codecept run api Tests\Users\Get
```

the following error is thrown:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Tests\ApiCest' not found in /Users/Username/Programming/PHP/Project/tests/api/Tests/Users/GetCest.php on line 12

This is the folder structure I'm using:

[image: Folder structure]

The `ApiCest.php` is only used to quickly bootstrap the other tests. Here is its content:

```
namespace Tests;

/*
 * This class is extended by the API tests.
 */
use ApiTester;

class ApiCest
{
    public function _before(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $I->prepareRequest();
    }

    public function _after(ApiTester $I)
    {
        // All API responses must be in a JSON format.
        $I->seeResponseIsJson();
    }
}
```

And this is how it's used in the `GetCest.php`:

```
namespace Tests\Users;

use ApiTester;
use Codeception\Util\HttpCode;
use Tests\ApiCest;

/*
 * Tests for the GET /users API endpoint.
 */
class GetCest extends ApiCest
{
    // Tests methods are here but omitted
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because `Tests\Users\GetCest` class extends `Tests\ApiCest` class, but autoloading is not set-up for test classes.

Add this block to your composer.json file:

```
"autoload":{
    "psr-4":{
        "Tests\\": "tests/api/Tests"
    }
}
```

If you already have `autoload psr-4` block, add just `"Tests\\": "tests/api/Tests"` line to it.

Comment: Thank you. I tried doing this before but it didn't work. I guess I didn't do it correctly :) Oh I also used `autoload-dev` instead of `autoload`.